# How to format a datetime string as defined below?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, format

How can I format a datetime string like 2020-04-30T22:30:00-04:00 to something like 2015-03-22T10:00:00+0900 in Python? The formatting, not the actual date.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: your example strings resemble completely different time and date - how are they related? how should this relation be taken into account by string formatting?

Comment: This question was already answered many many times on stackoverflow. Please use the search function.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 examples you have provided don't appear to have different formatting,
they're both [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) Extended format.

If you need to specify your own format you can use the datetime function [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and a format string, the reverse of this is strptime, which takes an input string and a format string and returns a datetime object

If you need to change timezones then the [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) object what your looking for

You might also be interested in the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

> Computing of relative deltas (next month, next year, next Monday, last week of month, etc);
>   Computing of relative deltas between two given date and/or datetime objects;
>
> Computing of dates based on very flexible recurrence rules, using a superset of the iCalendar specification.
>
> Parsing of RFC strings is supported as well. Generic parsing of dates in almost any string format
>
> Timezone (tzinfo) implementations for tzfile(5) format files (/etc/localtime,/usr/share/zoneinfo, etc), TZ environment string (in all known
>   formats), iCalendar format files, given ranges (with help from relative deltas), local machine timezone, fixed offset timezone, UTC timezone, and Windows registry-based time zones. Internal up-to-date world timezone information based on Olson’s database.
>
> Computing of Easter Sunday dates for any given year, using Western, Orthodox or Julian algorithms